# Visual Studio 2010 does not include C++ dlls in C# project when published

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, xna, publish

I have the following dependancies:

**C++ library <- C# library <- C# application**

Problem:
When I publish the C# application the C++ dlls are not included

How do I tell Visual Studio to also include the C++ dlls? (Note: since this is only a small project, a quick fix would already be enough)

Comment: Are these C++ libraries managed or un-managed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can solve this by including the C++ DLLs as files within the project.
(Project->Add Existing Item)

Then you right-click the DLL -> Properties and set the `Build Action` to `Content`, and select the `Copy to Output Directory` to either `Copy Always` or `Copy if newer`.

Answer (score -1):

in your project references, click on the dll you are using and in properties window,
set copy local to TRUE.

[image: set up the parameters]

Comment: External native C++ DLLs doesn't usually show up as managed references.

Comment: @MagnusJohansson: Did you thought in that case about using post build event to copy the dlls you need to the project?

Comment: You can browse for them, but they cannot be included (probably because they are unmanaged).

Comment: @cpoDesign, no I would do it as I described in my answer.

Comment: @MagnusJohansson: like your solution better.